# how to use one database per tenant with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, multiple-databases, db-charmer

I came into an uncommon problem, my client have 3 stores, and wants a web application
to manage each store separately. This would be a common multi tenant approach, but there
is an additional requirement: the client don't want to rely on an internet connection.
Therefore I can think of 2 solutions, on both there must be a server on each 
store with 1 instance of the database and 1 instance of the application running, if the internet connection fail, the client can use the application local instance.

- asynchronous database replication - each store local database is a replica of the online
  server database.
- make rails connect to a different database depending on the selected store. In this case there would be only 3 local databases (each at one store) to which the application online instance connects to. I saw [Guy's speech](http://aac2009.confreaks.com/06-feb-2009-14-30-writing-multi-tenant-applications-in-rails-guy-naor.html), and read about magic_multi_connections (magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_multi_connections), but it seem to be obsolete. [DbCharmer](http://kovyrin.github.com/db-charmer/index.html) seems to be a possible solution but I'm not sure if it will do it. 

  other posts related:

  - railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=48435
  - stackoverflow.com/questions/1825844/multiple-databases-in-rails

I would like to know the best architecture on this case. What would you do ?

Comment: As I will have only 3 tenants I decided to just install 3 instances of the system on heroku, each one accessing a database at one of the stores. To communicate the instances I can use a different database located at heroku, I will use establish_connection to change the database accessed by the StoresTransactions class.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/db-charmer/mMmYbwjel_U%5b1-25%5d) by DbCharmer developer Oleksiy Kovyrin:
"..if you use AR in a multi-process (single-threaded) environment, your case of having separate connections per-client is definitely possible.."

Comment: So what would be the case of standard servers like Glassfish or Jetty ? I'm new to RoR, but I think some server may be multi-threaded due to performance boosting ?